# Check if character in string has space behind

Tags: python, task

I am trying to write a function that breaks up camel casing by using a space between words. How do I check if char already has space behind?

```
def solution(s):
    space = ' '
    for chr in s:
        if chr.isupper() == True:
            new_str = s.replace(chr, space + chr)
    return new_str
```

Input:

```
"camelCaseWord"      # a word in camelCasing
```

Output:

```
"camel Case Word"    # separated by spaces where word starts with capital leter
```

My solution only gives me `"camelCase Word"`

Comment: camel cased strings don’t usually have spaces in them, what is new_str?

Comment: @Sayse  "camelCaseWord" => "camel Case Word"

Comment: @PatrickArtner - that’s the ops expected output right? I’m trying to understand why they might need to check for spaces at all since I’m guessing the input is “camelCaseWord”…

Comment: @Sayse they have a camelCaseWord and want a space seperated "camel Case Word" - to _"break up camel casing, using a space between words [.. to break it up]"_

Comment: @PatrickArtner - Exactly, so why the "if char already has space behind"? `"".join(f" {s}" if s.isupper() else s for s in "camelCaseWord")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does not work, because you always use the base  `s` as "source":

```
s = "someWordWithCases"
```

will replace `"W"` with `" W"`and store it in `new_str` ... then throw that result away and replace `"C"` with `" C"` - using the original `s` again - `"W"` are back in with no space added before them.

---

Creating strings by adding to them is wasteful. Strings are immutable so the old one is thrown away after you create a new one.

The solution is to split at capital letters into a list and then join the list elements with spaces:

### Yours minimally altered:

```
def solution(s):
    r = []
    for chr in s:
        # if chr is capital and ( r is empty OR the last one is not a space)         
        if chr.isupper() and (not r or  r[-1] != " "):            
            # add space then the capital letter
            r.append(" "+chr)
        else:
            # only add letter
            r.append(chr)
    return ''.join(r)
```

### Or version using slicing:

```
def solution(s):
    k = []
    start = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if c.isupper() and start != i:
            k.append(s[start:i])
            start = i

        if c == " ":
            k.append(s[start:i])
            start = i+1

    if i > start:
        k.append(s[start:])
    
    return ' '.join(k)


# some test cases are "more" then pure camelCaseSpelling
tests = ["startsLowerThenHasWords", "StartsCapitalThenHasWords", 
        "   starts with spaces no capitals", "  Has some Capitals",
        "has Capitals ABC and Others that areNotCapitals"]
maxL = max(len(t) for t in tests)

for t in tests:
    print(f"{t:<{maxL}} ==> {solution(t)}")
```

to get

```
startsLowerThenHasWords                         ==> starts Lower Then Has Words
StartsCapitalThenHasWords                       ==> Starts Capital Then Has Words
   starts with spaces no capitals               ==>    starts with spaces no capitals
  Has some Capitals                             ==>   Has some Capitals
has Capitals ABC and Others that areNotCapitals ==> has Capitals A B C and Others that are Not Capitals
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one? I used `enumerate` to get the index of iteration.

```
def solution(s):
    space = ' '
    space_positions = []
    for index, chr in enumerate(s):
        print(chr)
        if chr != space and chr.isupper() == True:
            if s[index - 1] != space:
                space_positions.insert(0, index)
    for index in space_positions:
        s = s[:index] + " " + s[index:]
    return s
```